# Change factor order in only 1 bar with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to invert the factors order in only 1 bar in ggplot 2. Reordering the data without define them as a factor usually works, but not in the newest versions.

Example: 
I want to invert the factors in the last column (green up, red down).

[image: Example]

```
library(ggplot2)

dados <- expand.grid(a = letters[1:5], b = letters[1:2])
dados$a <- paste(dados$a)
dados$b <- paste(dados$b)
dados$val <- rnorm(10, 5, 1)
ggplot(aes(x = a, y = val, fill = b), data = dados) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')

dados2 <- rbind(tail(dados, -1), head(dados, 1))
ggplot(aes(x = a, y = val, fill = b), data = dados2) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity') # Used to work :/
```

Comment: One thought would be to add a different layer for the last column (I know it's annoying), but I don't know if there is to make stacking order follow the order in the data.

Answer (score 3):

I have assigned two additional parameters to `e` in `column b` see below `c` and `d`:

```
    a b    val
2  b a 4.504735
3  c a 5.396658
4  d a 6.796288
5  e c 5.900308
6  a b 3.900510
7  b b 4.454316
8  c b 5.411198
9  d b 6.389902
10 e d 4.458425
1  a a 4.986175
```

by `scale_fill_manual` I invert the two colours

```
ggplot(aes(x = a, y = val, fill = b), data = dados2) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("a"= "red", "b"= "green",'c'= "green", "d"="red"))
```